# Make bounty messages editable

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Would it please be possible to add the ability to edit a bounty message?

I recently posted a bounty, but forgot to include some details by mistake and made some formatting errors, as I was unable to preview the message prior to posting it. Being able to edit the message in such cases would be of benefit to both answerers and readers of the post in general.

The message does not have to be editable for the entire duration of the bounty, but it would help to have an x-minute window within which the message remains editable after the bounty has been posted. Something similar to the way in which comments are editable for 5 minutes after being posted.

Comment: Welcome to Math meta. FYI, there are several quite similar posts here, e.g., [Cannot edit my bounty notice](/q/20731), [There should be a way to edit bounty text.](/q/20176), [How do I edit the description for a bounty after I have started a bounty](/q/32696), [Is it possible to edit bounty messages?](/q/23213), etc. Also, there's [Add a grace period for bounty removal / reversal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111967) on the network Meta. Finally, on that other site, there's the FAQ post [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065).

Comment: main meta: [Editing bounty messages, is it finally time for a little "Love"? (anti-Doh! feature request)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324104/303080)